# Can I build an efficient frontier using matrix algebra?

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, portfolio, covariance

If i have a vector of expected returns $A$, a covariance matrix $C$ and a vector of the corresponding weights $W$ for each investment, is it possible to generate the efficient frontier with vector algebra? I am sure I have seen the efficient frontier in matrix form somewhere but I cant remember it, something like $W^TACW$. I want to generate an efficient frontier in R by randomly selecting portfolio weights So I just need the matrix notation.

Comment: the formulas were derived by R. C. Merton in a famous paper "An Analytic Derivation of the Efficient Portfolio Frontier" which is available online. It is also in many books for ex Chi-Fu Huang: *foundations for financial economics* pages 64 and 67.

Comment: adding to previous answer, only the unconstrained efficient frontier, where short selling is allowed, can be solved analytically with matrix algebra. The constrained efficient frontier cannot be solved analytically